# how to redirect to main page

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess

I will be moving to a new server and I need to make sure that everyone, no matter where on the site they come are redirected to a particular page. I think I need to do it with .htaccess Any suggestions how?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean pages from your old site should be redirected to this page? You do not want to redirect all traffic to a page unless it is a single page site ;)

Comment: I need all visitors to my site to be redirected to something like maintenance.php

Comment: Sorry, I found the following page with instruction of exactly what I needed: [http://www.techiecorner.com/97/redirect-to-maintenance-page-during-upgrade-using-htaccess/](http://www.techiecorner.com/97/redirect-to-maintenance-page-during-upgrade-using-htaccess/)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !maintenance\.php /maintenance.php
```

Answer (score 1):

create a file with name maintenance.php.

Then put

```
header("Location:maintenance.php");
```

in index.php in your root folder .

:)

Comment: That would only redirect requests to `index.php`. Users would still be able to access other pages.